# adding cocos2d class to xcode project

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

we have an xcode project that is listening to audio-jack signals and should perform animations.
Now i have the xcode working,and the cocos2d animation working ,i need to mix them together.
i know cocos2d has so many stuff that must be included to it,so it is a problem to just add a cocos2d file to my classes folder. Also adding my classes to existing cocos2d project is not clear.

my question is, what is the better way of doing so, and how can i call from cocos2d to another xcode class, or vise versa,how to call to a cocos2d class from regular xcode project.

when the app is loads,i need to load the cocos2d classes and then to call my classes and listen to audio-jack, and then  call back cocos2d class if needed.

i found very complicated ways to do so, and i need something simple, or a code example.
thanks very much .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basic project setup with Cocos2D sounds like your already most of the way there.  You should be able to get the input from your audio signal class inside of a `CCScene` or `CCLayer` instance.  In your custom `CCScene` or `CCLayer` class definition you'll want to have an `update` method as described here...

[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:draw_update?s[]=update](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3adraw_update?s%5B%5D=update)

In your update method you can then get the latest stats from your audio signal class.  I assume this is what you want to do but correct me if I'm wrong.

There's a bunch of tutorials and lessons you might find useful as well if you haven't already looked into it...

[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_2._your_first_game](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3alesson_2._your_first_game)
[http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=getting+started+with+cocos+2d](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=getting%20started%20with%20cocos%202d)

Hope some of this helps.